# Eloquent or Query builder search utilising pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have what appears on the face of it to be a simple requirement - search for all Profiles that have a location equal to $locationId and have a specific service ($serviceId), but I'm not sure how to add a where condition that queries via a pivot table?

My models are as follows:

```
class Profile extends Model {

    public function services() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Service', 'profile_services', 'profile_id', 'service_id');
    }

}

class Service extends Model {}
```

What I want to do is something along the lines of this:

```
$results = Profile::where('location_id', '=', $locationId)->where('services.id', '=', $serviceId)->get();
```

**Note** I'm aware that `->where('services.id', '=', $serviceId)` is incorrect (I've put it here to better explain what I'm trying to achieve) but I'd like to know I'd do this using either Eloquent or the DB query builder.

Comment: try what you want to do, it should already work. laravel-4 has that.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I get an exception - 'Column services.id not found'. Even after adding `Profile::with(['services']...`

Comment: you query relations with `has` instead of `where` from top of my head.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can filter relations with `whereHas`

```
$results = Profile::where('location_id', '=', $locationId)
                  ->whereHas('services', function($query) use ($serviceId){
                      $query->where('services.id', '=', $serviceId);
                  })->get();
```

Comment: Aha, just what I was looking for. Cheers @lukasgeiter

Comment: Great. Thanks, you saved me today